# Kafka Producer, multi DC failover support

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have two distinct kafka clusters located in different data centers - DC1 and DC2. How to organize kafka producer failover between two DCs? If primary kafka cluster (DC1) becomes unavailable, I want producer to switch to failover kafka cluster (DC2) and continue publishing to it? Producer also should be able to switch back to primary cluster, once it is available. Any good patterns, existing libs, approaches, code examples?

Answer (score 2):

Each partition of the Kafka topic your producer is publishing to has a separate leader, often spread across multiple brokers in the cluster, so the producer is connected to many “primary” brokers simultaneously. Should any one of them fail another In Sync Replica (ISR) will be  elected as leader and automatically take over. You do not need to do anything in your client app for it to reconnect to the new leader(s), retry any failed requests, and continue.

If this is for Multi-Data Center (MDC) failover then things get much more complicated depending on if the client apps die as well or if they keep running and need just their cluster connections to failover. Offsets are not preserved across multiple Kafka clusters so while producers are simpler, consumers need to call GetOffsetsForTimes() upon failover.

For a great write up of the the MDC failover modes and best practices see the MDC Whitepaper here: https://www.confluent.io/white-paper/disaster-recovery-for-multi-datacenter-apache-kafka-deployments/

Since you asked only about producers, your app can detect if the primary cluster is down (say for a certain number of retries) and then instead of attempting to reconnect, it can instead connect to another brokerlist from the secondary cluster. Alternatively you can redirect the dns name of the brokerlist hosts to point to the secondary cluster.

Comment: I updated my question to be more precise. I want multi DC failover, which is not coming out-of-the-box. I have two separate kafka clusters.

Comment: Is your Producer also in DC1 and so it needs to be restarted in DC2 when there is a failover?

Comment: Vanilla kafka client doesn't support MDC features like cluster down detection and connection switching. I'm wondering if some kafka client for MDC exists which offers all these features out of the box? I really don't want to code it